# File Upload Error, when having danish character in image file name

Tags: php, html

I am using a third party API named Podio. 
i want to upload file using api's function and its working cool

Only problem is when i updoad a file named like "Skærmbillede.jpg" its return this error

**Fatal error: Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "The request entity could not be decoded. The following charsets were attempted: ['us-ascii', 'utf-8']" Request URL: http://api.podio.com/file/v2/ Request Body: null Stack Trace: #0 /home/meetuniv/public_html/anjali/tidligerebestilinger/lib/Podio.php(271): Podio::request('POST', '/file/v2/', Array, Array) #1 /home/meetuniv/public_html/anjali/tidligerebestilinger/models/PodioFile.php(40): Podio::post('/file/v2/', Array, Array) #2 /home/meetuniv/public_html/anjali/tidligerebestilinger/new_request.php(43): PodioFile::upload('/tmp/phpPRXwtP', 'Sk?rmbillede.pn...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/meetuniv/public_html/anjali/tidligerebestilinger/lib/Podio.php on line 208**

just because "Skærmbillede.jpg" file name contatin danish character.
is there any way to do? i can change or replace file name danish character with suitable character.

Thanks to have a look...

Comment: The API says it accepts UTF-8 encoded data – so just encoding the filename in UTF-8 should do, I’d say …

Comment: Ya thanks @CBroe $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8"); is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8");
```

Helps in my situation. Thanks for taking look. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to convert the name of the image while uploading it on the server since server can't handle those characters. So you need to change æ to ae or something like that. That means you'll have to fiddle with the plugin you're using.
You could do http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Or you can simply write to people that they should rename their picture before they upload it.

Comment: Encoding is the best and proper way to do it. thanks

Comment: Yes and (æøå) server can't handle but encoding it even when your image containing (%) sign, it will be stored on the server. Then you can decode it again if you need to show the original file name.